# Вопрос инициализации методов в статическом методе интерфейса Java

Tags: java

Есть несколько классов, которые имплементят интерфей. каждый класс реализует определенную задачу
К примеру один из них

```
 class IntArrayFactory implements Factory<int[]> {

    int a = 10, b = 20;
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int i = a + rnd.nextInt((b-a) + 1);
    int[] array = new int[i];

    @Override
    public int[] create() {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            array[j] = rnd.nextInt(101);
        }
        return array;
    }
}

class Sorter implements Sort<int[]> {

    @Override
    public void run(int[] array) {
        Arrays.sort(array);
    }

}
class Writer implements ObjectWriter<int []>{
StringBuilder str;
    @Override
    public void write(int[] object) throws IOException {
        str = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i< object.length; ){
            str.append(object[i]);
            str.append(", ");
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {

    }



}


public final class OneDimensionalArrays implements Exercise {

    /**
     * Фабрика, создающая одномерный массив случайной
     * длины, содержащие случайные числа в интервале
     * от {@code 0} до {@code 100}.
     *<p>
     * Длина массивов должна колебаться в диапазоне от
     * 10, до 20 элементов.
     */
    private IntArrayFactory factory ;




    /**
     * Выполняет сортировку одномерного массива по
     * возрастанию.
     */
    private Sorter sort;

    /**
     * Объект, отвечающий за вывод одномерного массива в
     * консоль.
     * <p>
     * Массив следет выводить в одну строку, разделяя
     * элементы массива запятыми и пробелами. Массив должен
     * быть заключён в квадратные скобки.
     * <p>
     * Например: {@code [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]}
     */
    private ObjectWriter<int[]> writer;

    public OneDimensionalArrays() throws IOException {

        run();

        // TODO(Студент): Выполнить инициализацию полей класса OneDimensionalArrays
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not implemented!");
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public void run() throws IOException {
        int[] array = factory.create();
        sort.run(array);
        writer.write(array);
    }
}
```

сам интерфейс

```
package ru.avalon.java.ocpjp.labs;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import ru.avalon.java.ocpjp.labs.tasks.arrays.OneDimensionalArrays;
import ru.avalon.java.ocpjp.labs.tasks.arrays.TwoDimensionalArrays;
import ru.avalon.java.ocpjp.labs.tasks.objects.Inheritance;

/**
 * Абстратное представление об упражнении.
 */
public interface Exercise {

    /**
     * Тело упражнения.
     * <p>
     * Содержит основной код упражнения.
     *
     * @throws Exception в случае возникновения исключительной ситуации
     */
    void run() throws Exception;

    /**
     * Фабричный метод, порождающий задания на основании переданых аргументов
     * командной строки.
     * <p>
     * Пользователь должен передавать название задания, с использованием
     * аргумента {@code /exercise}, {@code -exercise}, {@code /e} или
     * {@code -e}.
     * <p>
     * Например: {@code java -jar lab1.jar -e comparison} где:
     * <b>{@code syntax}</b> - название задания, которое следует запустить.
     *
     * @param args аргументы командной строки
     * @return Экземпляр класса, реализующего задание
     */
    static Exercise create(String[] args) throws IOException {

        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not implemented!");
    }
}
```

и главный класс

```
public class Lab implements Exercise {

    /**
     * Точка входа в приложение.
     * <p>
     * При входе в приложение, выполняется создание получение экземпляра задания
     * с использованием фабричного метода {@code create} интерфейса
     * {@link Exercise}.
     *
     * @param args аргументы командной строки
     * @throws java.io.IOException
     */
    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException, Exception {



        Exercise exercise = Exercise.create(args);
        try {
            exercise.run();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }

        /*
         * TODO(Студент): Пользуясь терминалом, запустить все задания лабораторной работы
         * 1. Запустить задание OneDimensionalArrays
         * 2. Запустить задание TwoDimensionalArrays
         * 3. Запустить задание Inheritance
         */
    }

    @Override
    public void run() throws Exception {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
}
```

как реализовать инициализацию класса OneDimensionalArrays указанным способом? не понимаю как это сделать

Comment: `Exercise exercise = new OneDimensionalArrays()`. ведь классы инициализируются через new. почему так не хотите?

Comment: То есть запускает конструктор и выполняется задание.

Comment: @SeniorPomidor с консоли будут вводиться данные (название задания) которые будут передаваться как аргумент args в метод create. и там уже будет создаваться экземпляр нужного класса. в статическом методе create пробовал писать OneDemensionalArrays array = new OneDemensionalArrays(). Но выдает ошибку NullPointerException при вызове int[] array = factory.create(). При этом я проверял этот класс отдельно и все в нем работает

Comment: @Storano правильно. потому что private IntArrayFactory factory  у вас null/ поэтому NullPointerException при вызове любых методов factory

Comment: @SeniorPomidor, блин, точно. Забыл совсем...*facepalm